# Generate Java classes from .dll

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jnaerator

I have a device which I want to access from java. The only way to do this is using a dll library provided by the manufacturer. I have read about JNI, JNA etc. and maybe there is a tool outside which analyses the dll and generates the Java classes automatically.

Does anybody know a way of doing this?

Comment: you can start [here](http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part1-java-native-interface/)

Comment: @TechExchange that fails the "automatically" requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we used [jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/) to generate the Java classes for accessing the the .dll. The jawin typebrowser tool was the only one that could handle the C++ .dll we were trying to access.

Unfortunately the jawin project is no longer developed. The last version is dated to early 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this - [JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/) can "compile" native headers in order to generate JNA mappings, with some limited C++ support.

Comment: It doesn't seem to support parsing DLLs. You'd need a second tool that would decompile a DLL to a C/C++ header.